# Ecto model update multiple relationships

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to insert an Ecto model in the table `worklogs` which has two relationships `user_id` and `issue_id`. I find that when I try to create a changeset for a worklog with valid integers for these two fields, they are not included in the changeset and are null in the resulting `worklog` and API response. I've made sure that a `user` and `issue` exists with the primary keys I'm inserting with the `worklog`.

I've also looked at the documentation and it seems like `build_assoc/3` is the way to update relationships, but it seems to be limited to inserting for a single relationship. From the docs, I think I should do something like this:

```
user = #get the user
worklog = Ecto.build_assoc(user, :worklogs, worklog_params)
```

But I've never declared `worklogs` on `user`, so how does it know to set `user_id` on the worklog? Also, how do I subsequently add the `issue_id`?

Schemas:

```
  schema "worklogs" do
    field :start_time, Ecto.DateTime
    field :end_time, Ecto.DateTime
    belongs_to :issue, MyApi.Issue
    belongs_to :user, MyApi.User

    timestamps()
  end

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  schema "issues" do
    field :title, :string
    field :status, :string
    field :description, :string
    field :estimate, :float

    timestamps()
  end
```

Controller logic:

```
def create(conn, %{"worklog" => worklog_params}) do
    changeset = Worklog.changeset(%Worklog{}, worklog_params)

    IO.inspect changeset #user_id and issue_id are not present

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, worklog} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> put_resp_header("location", worklog_path(conn, :show, worklog))
        |> render("show.json", worklog: worklog)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(MyApi.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

POST request:

```
{
  "worklog": {
    "start_time": "2017-04-08 02:20:00",
    "end_time": "2017-04-08 02:30:00",
    "issue_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant schemas?

Comment: @JustinWood Good idea, updated.

Comment: That new error should be unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to see your changeset to provide a concrete answer. However, I suspect your missing `user_id` and `issue_id` in the `cast` call in your changeset. Ecto will not add fields to the changes if the fields are not listed in the cast list.

The phoenix model generator does not add belongs_to fields to the cast operation. I usually add them manually.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. I had assumed that the belongs_to fields would be considered in the changeset but they were not automatically. Adding them manually fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In this case of multiple relations needing to be set, it is probably better to just set them explicitly like this

```
%Worklog{user_id: user.id, issue_id: issue.id}
|> Worklog.changset(worklog_params)
|> Repo.insert()
```

You may also benefit from putting relations onto your user and issue schemas so that you are able to easier query for the worklogs that relate to a given user or issue.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I think I found my problem which is that user_id and issue_id weren't being considered in the `Worklog.changeset` function. I've now added them but am getting a new error. Will update question